Which 60's or 70's TV series or movie had a sidekick that regularly ambushed the main character?
I thought it was the 60's TV series, "The Green Hornet" where Kato would ambush the Green Hornet to keep the Green Hornet sharp and on his toes but I can't find reference to that so now I think I may be remembering wrong.  Does anybody know of a TV series or movie where the sidekick would attack the main character like that - usually from a dark corner?

Er, I think you mean the other Cato, from The Pink Panther.

OK!  That was my confusion...the Pink Panther movies had Cato (also known as Kato in one movie) ambush Clouseau regularly.  If you make that an answer, I'll choose it, @Walt

The movie "The Pink Panther" with Peter Sellers. Wikipedia's description of the sidekick:

Cato (spelled "Kato" in A Shot in the Dark) is Clouseau's manservant, and an expert in martial arts. It is unclear whether he believes Clouseau to be a great detective or whether he merely humors him. It is a running joke that he is instructed to attack Clouseau unexpectedly, to keep Clouseau's combat skills and vigilance sharp. Cato often takes these instructions to the point of ambushing Clouseau in his own house or at times when Clouseau obviously would prefer not to be disturbed.


Walt led me to the correct answer.  In the absence of Walt creating an answer as I suggested, I have to acknowledge @CWallach's answer as correct, though a nod to Walt would have been "nice". :-)
